# Mutable vs. immutable borrows in closure?

Tags: rust

I can't figure out how to get the following to work.  I think I need the closure to borrow by `&mut Vec`, but I don't know how to express that.  This is distilled from a larger function, but shows the same error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 10];

    let next = |i| (i + 1) % v.len();

    v[next(1usize)] = 1;

    v.push(13);

    v[next(2usize)] = 1;    
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> a.rs:9:5
  |
5 |     let next = |i| {
  |                --- immutable borrow occurs here
6 |         (i + 1) % v.len()
  |                   - first borrow occurs due to use of `v` in closure
...
9 |     v[next(1usize)] = 1;
  |     ^ ---- immutable borrow later used here
  |     |
  |     mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Note this doesn't appear to be different than `v[(1usize + 1) % v.len()] = 1;`. You have both a mutable and immutable borrow.

Comment: @Schwern So it is.  You are right, same error.  How would that be fixed?

Comment: `let vlen = (1usize + 1) % v.len(); v[vlen] = 1;` is the simple answer so nothing is holding onto the immutable borrow while you're mutating. For what you're trying to accomplish, I feel like this is what an iterator is for.

Comment: Now assume that the logic is more complicated and ought to be encapsulated in a closure for repeated use.  How would that work?

Comment: I don't think it does work. Rust has a very strict idea of how things work, and I don't think closures offer the kind of freedom you might be used to from other languages. The closure has to hold onto a borrow which means you can't mutably borrow the same vector for anything else. You might be able to do something with lifetimes (I can't help there) but I don't think closures give you that kind of control. Iterators do.

Comment: "I think I need the closure to borrow by &mut Vec" That wouldn't help; you'd have two simultaneous mutable borrows, and that's not allowed either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to do it with a closure, you will have to pass the vector by parameter:

```
let next = |v: &Vec<_>, i| (i + 1) % v.len();
```

This makes the closure borrow per-call, rather than capture for the scope. You still need to separate the borrows, though:

```
let j = next(&v, 1usize);
v[j] = 1;
```

To make your life easier, you can put everything inside the closure instead:

```
let next = |v: &mut Vec<_>, i, x| {
    let j = (i + 1) % v.len();
    v[j] = x;
};
```

Which allows you to simply do:

```
next(&mut v, 1usize, 1);
next(&mut v, 2usize, 2);
// etc.
```

This pattern is useful for cases where you are writing a closure just for avoiding local code repetition (which I suspect is why you are asking given the comments).

Comment: thanks for the response.  Yes, I was trying to avoid local code repetition primarily - and your example is helpful.  I think I understand now.  The closure captures immutably captured `v` for its lifetime, meaning I couldn't mutate it later.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, the closure capturing `v` makes it a problem for as long it remains around.

Answer (score 2):

Since the closure only needs the length of the [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html). Then instead, you can just get that prior to the closure. Then you avoid the whole borrowing issue, as the closure doesn't need to borrow `v` anymore.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 10];

    let len = v.len();
    let next = |i| (i + 1) % len;

    v[next(1usize)] = 1;
}
```

---

Assuming your closure is not dependent on other things, then instead of a closure, you could define a trait with a method that does that.

For simplicity let's call the trait `VecExt` and the method `set`.

```rust
trait VecExt<T> {
    fn set(&mut self, index: usize, value: T);
}

impl<T> VecExt<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn set(&mut self, index: usize, value: T) {
        let len = self.len();
        self[(index + 1) % len] = value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 10];

    v.set(1, 1);

    v.push(13);

    v.set(2, 1);
}
```

Comment: In a more real world example, `len` will be dynamic.  And who knows, perhaps I might want to do other things to the `Vec` within the closure.  The challenge posed by creating a minimal repro to post on this site, I guess.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 are you able to update the example to better reflect the issue / use case?

Comment: Updated to demonstrate that the length of the vector may change.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 is your actual code, especially the closure depended on other things? If not, then instead of a closure you could define a trait with a method that does what the closure currently does. Would that suffice?

Answer (score 1):

A closure probably isn't the right tool for the job.  The compiler is unhappy because your closure has taken a reference against your `Vec`, but then while that closure reference is still outstanding you're trying to mutate the `Vec`. Under Rust's borrow rules, that's not allowed.

The most straightforward approach would be storing your data inside a struct, and making `next` a member function.  That way, there's no closure taking references; it can just check the length only when needed.

```rust
struct WrapVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> WrapVec<T> {
    fn wrap_next(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut T {
        let index = (index + 1) % self.0.len();
        &mut self.0[index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = WrapVec(vec![0; 10]);
    *v.wrap_next(1) = 1;
    v.0.push(13);
    *v.wrap_next(2) = 1;
}
```

If you want to be able to apply this function to any `Vec`, then you may find it useful to define a new trait. For example:

```rust
trait WrapNext<T> {
    fn wrap_next(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut T;
}

impl<T> WrapNext<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn wrap_next(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut T {
        let index = (index + 1) % self.len();
        &mut self[index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 10];
    *v.wrap_next(1) = 1;
    v.push(13);
    *v.wrap_next(2) = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers here, you can use a macro to scope `v` so you don't have to pass it in every call:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 10];

    macro_rules! next {
        // rule to get an index
        ($i: expr) => {
            ($i + 1) % v.len()
        };
        // rule to mutate the vector
        ($i: expr => $v: expr) => {{
            let ind = next!($i);
            v[ind] = $v;
        }};
    };
    // get an index
    let ind = next!(1usize);
    // mutate the vector
    v[ind] = 1;
    v.push(13);
    // or, with the mutation syntax
    next!(2usize => 3);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```